# Changing entry in an array while looping through it

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
arr = ["red","green","blue","yellow"]

arr.each do |colour|
  if colour == "red"
    colour = "green"
  end
end

puts arr.inspect
```

The above code outputs:

```
["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
```

but why not?

```
["green", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
```

I thought that colour was a reference to the current element in the array, and whatever i did to it would effect that array element?

Comment: I edited a comment bellow including mutation objects, with taht you can use index and get desired result:

arr.each { |colour| colour[0..colour.length] = 'green' if colour == 'red' }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're inside the `arr.each` block, the `colour` variable is bound to one of the objects in the `arr` array.

However, as soon as you make the assignment `colour = "green"` in the block, now the `colour` variable is bound to a new object (namely a String with a value of `"green"`), and the original `arr` remains unaffected.

One way to achieve what you're talking about would be:

```
arr.each_index do |i|
  arr[i] = "green" if arr[i] == "red"
end
```

which manipulates the array directly.

Comment: `.map` would probably be better.

Comment: Agreed, `arr.map { |x| x == "red" ? "green" : x }` would work fine too.

Answer (score 4):

Colour is indeed innitially a reference to the current element in the array, but with 'colour="green"' it now references a **new** string. The old one is left unchanged. For experimenting, try replacing

```
colour = "green"
```

with one or more of

```
colour.replace "green"
colour.capitalize! #not capitalize, which would give a new string again
colour << "ish"
```

All of which operate on the existing string, not creating a new one.

Comment: In C++ the concept of a "reference" is described as a voodoo doll, whatever you do to the reference you are actually doing the object that is pointed to. It seems the concept of a reference in Ruby is completely different.

Comment: Further to my above comment, given the variable "colour" from my original example, how would you manipulate the memory it points to directly rather than the variable itself, without using any specific array functions? I guess what I am asking is what does colour.replace do under the hood?

Comment: @pingu `colour` is not a reference; it is a variable, which _holds_ a reference to another object. Variable assignment always replaces the contents of the variable with a different reference, while method invocation is carried out on the referenced object.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, in order to transform an array into another array, in Ruby you don't use `each` method, but `map` method instead (code by user sflinter above):

```
arr.map { |x| x == "red" ? "green" : x }
```

Or, to be a bit more general, given the transformation map:

```
mapping = {'red' => 'green', 'blue' => 'yellow'}
```

we can do something like

```
p arr.map {|e| mapping[e] || e} # => ["green", "green", "yellow", "yellow"]
```

PS: As Phrogz suggested below, `map` creates a new instance of array and, if you planned to keep the modified array in the same variable, you should assign the result of `map` to it.

On the other hand, there's `map`'s evil twin called `map!`, which modifies the original array in-place (so no need to assign it back), saving some space and time, but breaking the pure functional programming concept that functions shouldn't have side-effects.

Comment: You should modify your answer to clarify the difference between `map` returning a new array, and the need to assign it to a new variable, versus the availability of `map!` for in-place mutation.

Comment: The .map evil twin is great for saving lines of code, I use it a lot, but is a lot more prone to errors when it encounters unexpected situations (such as nils, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

What I am about to write is *not* the recommended way to do this, but note that since Strings are mutable in Ruby you could write the original code as follows:

```
arr.each do |colour|
  colour.replace "green" if colour == "red"
end

p arr
#=> ["green", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the arr element directly by indexing using each_with_index:

```
arr = ["red","green","blue","yellow"]

arr.each_with_index do |colour, i|
  if colour == "red"
    arr[i] = "green"
  end
end

puts arr.inspect
```